# Error message into Laravel 8 with Inertia does not work

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I have a form into a modal, and it is working fine. Now I wanted to add an error message, if someone forget to add some text into the field name.

I added into AppServiceProvider

```
Inertia::share([
    'errors' => function () {
        return Session::get('errors')
            ? Session::get('errors')->getBag('default')->getMessages()
                : (object) [];
    },
]);
```

Into the Controller I added

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => ['required'],
    ])->validate();
```

Into the index.vue I added

```
<div class="mb-4">
     <label for="name" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Name:</label>
     <input type="text" class="shadow appearance-none border-gray-300 rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="name" v-model="form.name">
     <div v-if="$page.errors.name">{{ $page.errors.name[0] }}</div>
</div>
```

When the modal should open, I see this error message into the console and the script aborts.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
```

When I delete this line, the script works, but I do not see any error message

```
<div v-if="$page.errors.name">{{ $page.errors.name[0] }}</div>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Since Inertia apps never generate `422` responses, Inertia needs another way to determine if a response includes validation errors. To do this, Inertia checks the `page.props.errors` object for the existence of any errors. So you are accessing a property that does not exist and that is the cause of the error.

You also don't need to share errors with inertia, as Laravel does it for you automatically. You just have to make sure to add the errors property and be able to set it.

Then add the property in your `.vue` file

```js
export default {
  props: {
    errors: Object,
  },
  ...
```

And in your template then do something like this

```html
<div v-if="errors.name">{{ errors.name}}</div>
```

If you're using the form helper, it's not necessary to use error bags and neither what I said above, since validation errors are automatically scoped to the form object.
So if you want to take advantage of the potential of Inertia forms you should do something like this.

```html
<div v-if="form.errors.name">{{ form.errors.name}}</div>
```